# how to change disk order shown at sidebar in thunar of xfce4?

Tags: xfce, udev

I have pc running with dual boot, win/debian+xfce4, and it shares some partition (those D/E/F in windows,ntfs). The partitions are sorted `F/E/D` at sidebar in thunar of xfce4. Is there any udev rules to reverse them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game but this is a question put but not yet answered in various forums, so for future reference:

I have just changed the order of Devices in Thunar by reordering the `/dev/disk/by-uuid/...` entries in `/etc/fstab` in Mint XFCE.

May be worth a try.